# json data parsing error android studio

Tags: java, android, json

[image]  Giving the error In EXCEPTION .... json data parsing error in catch in postexecute metod please help how to resolve.when the data entered in it it and it start working smothly but when time to send data it show that json data parsing error

```
/**
 * Created by Mian on 2/28/2016.
 */
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
public class SignupActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private Context context;
    public SignupActivity(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        String fullName = arg0[0];
        String userName = arg0[1];
        String passWord = arg0[2];
        String phoneNumber = arg0[3];
        String emailAddress = arg0[4];
        String link;
        String data;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        String result;
        try {
            data = "?fullname=" + URLEncoder.encode(fullName, "UTF-8");
            data += "&username=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8");
            data += "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(passWord, "UTF-8");
            data += "&phonenumber=" + URLEncoder.encode(phoneNumber, "UTF-8");
            data += "&emailaddress=" + URLEncoder.encode(emailAddress, "UTF-8");
            link = "http://livethuglife.com/signup.php" + data;
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            result = bufferedReader.readLine();
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        String jsonStr = result.toString();
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");
                if (query_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Data inserted successfully. Signup successfull.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (query_result.equals("FAILURE")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Data could not be inserted. Signup failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't connect to remote database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error parsing JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't get any JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is error you are getting?

Comment: json data parsing error

Comment: that is your error, what is error in logcat?

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(String result) in this method the catch condition is done and show me that json data parsing error

Comment: catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error parsing JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

Comment: Please put in your question the `Exception` and also an example of the `String` you are receiving back.

Comment: **1.** Make sure you are getting Response as JsonObject **2.** that json object has a field called `query_result`. **3.** OR Post your logcat error of JsonException without that cant help

Comment: 02-29 18:31:22.328 2386-2399/com.example.mian.phpmysql E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab856d80
02-29 18:31:22.381 2386-2399/com.example.mian.phpmysql W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-29 18:31:22.381 2386-2399/com.example.mian.phpmysql W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabfe96a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-29 18:31:24.355 2386-2399/com.example.mian.phpmysql E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab855f80

Answer (score 1):

Better to use a `Class` as per your `Form` that you have been Posting to the `Server`.

1. A Simple Java class with the number of field which needs to carry complete data of form to the server. Like i have defined as `SignUp` Class.
2. Then make a `object` of that `Class SignUp` Filled the `object` to corresponding **values** that you want to post to the **server**.
3. Now Change that `object` to `JSON` Using Google `gson.jar` (You may download it by searching it on the internet)

   > A Simple Example I have shown to you..

> A Simple **POJO** `Class` **SignUP**

```
Class SignUP{
   private String fullname;
   private String username;
   private String passoword;  // Define Number of Variable as per your Need
   private String phonenumber;
   private String emailaddress;

       //Getter and Setters Method.
}
```

Now Instantiate your class and try **Google** `GSON` library jars to parse it as `JSON Object`.

> A Simple **Logic** to Convert `Object` of  `Class` **SignUP** to `JSON` .

```
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    String fullName = arg0[0];
    String userName = arg0[1];
    String passWord = arg0[2];
    String phoneNumber = arg0[3];
    String emailAddress = arg0[4];

    SignUP obj = new SignUP();
    obj.setFullName(URLEncoder.encode(fullName, "UTF-8"));
    obj.setUserName(URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8"));
    obj.setPassword(URLEncoder.encode(passWord, "UTF-8"););
    obj.setPhoneNumber(URLEncoder.encode(phoneNumber,"UTF-8"););
    obj.setEmailAddress(URLEncoder.encode(emailAddress, "UTF-8"););
     
    Gson gson = new Gson();
     
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(obj));
    }
```

Output:

```
{
  "fullName":"FullName",
  "username":"Lokesh",
  "password":"Gupta",
  "phonenumber":"73479273423",
  "emailaddress":"abc @abc.com"
}
```

You may also try [How to Convert Java Object to  JSON Using Google GSON API](http://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/google-gson-tutorial-convert-java-object-to-from-json/)

Comment: will you please eleborate

Comment: is it appropriate to understand i think. If u have a little knowledge of java..

Thank You

Comment: pass something to the class object that you make so what will i pass..?

Comment: Library have multiple method that can enable u to change object directly to the the json. 
gaon.toJson(obj). Just explore the Library please . u will got your answer